# Recalculate XY Extent Option Not Available

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, enterprise-geodatabase, extents

I am unable to recalculate the XY extent of a feature class. I am attempting to do so within the Feature Extent tab within the Properties window accessed from ArcCatalog. The Recalculate button, however, is greyed out. The feature class is within an ArcSDE geodatabase and I am not the DBO. Any ideas on why this option is not available?

[image]

Comment: You must be the table owner to modify the properties of a layer.

Comment: I'm no arcsde expert but your screenshot appears to imply that your current extent has no width or height, may be that has something to do with it?

Comment: I just edited photo to conceal location and didn't catch that. I have edited question. @Hornbydd I think Vince may be correct.